# How to use ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly inside my powershell code in SQL command

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need to use ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly with my SQL command in powershell which is connecting to a replica database. Can anyone help ?

Since replicas servers could not be accessed directly. So I need to use this command. I know how to manually do it but need help on code.

```
$SQLQuery = "SELECT x.SCode, x.DatabaseName FROM dbo.Logins x ORDER BY x.SCode"
$auth = @{Username = $SQLUserName; Password = $SQLAdminPassword}

try
{
    $allTenants = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQLQuery -ServerInstance $SQLServerName -Database 'SShared'-QueryTimeout -0 @Auth -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Log -LogFileName $logfile -LogEntry ("Found {0} tenants" -f $allTenants.Count)
}
```

I am geeting the below error using this -

> Exception Message A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
>
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 
>   - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways that you can do this.

## Easy way

### dbatools

There is a PowerShell module for interacting with SQL Server created by the SQL Server community called dbatools.
In the module, there is a function called `Invoke-DbaQuery` which is essentially a wrapper for `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.

This function has a parameter, `-ReadOnly`, that you can use that was created exactly for this scenario.

```
# Changing your $auth to a PSCredential object.
$cred = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::New(
    $SqlUserName,
    (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $SqlAdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force))

# Splatting the parameters for read-ability.
$QueryParams = @{
    Query = $SQLQuery
    SqlInstance = $SQLServerName
    Database = 'SShared'
    QueryTimeout = 0
    SqlCredential = $cred
    ReadOnly = $true # <-- Specifying read-only intent.
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
}
$allTenants = Invoke-DbaQuery @QueryParams
```

## Other way

### Invoke-Sqlcmd

If you can't, won't, don't want to use dbatools, you can still use `Invoke-Sqlcmd`. The latest release at the time of writing, has the option to specify the parameter `-ConnectionString`.

You can state that it's read-only there.

```
# Splatting again for read-ability.
$SqlcmdParams = @{
    Query = $SQLQuery
    QueryTimeout = 0
    ConnectionString = "Data Source=$SQLServerName;Initial Catalog=SShared;User ID=$SqlUserName;Password=$SqlAdminPassword;Integrated Security=false;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" # <-- Specifying read-only intent.
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
}
Invoke-Sqlcmd @SqlcmdParams
```